# A=QR, Prove diagonal elements of R are eucledian distance from column to linear span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a problem to prove that diagonal entries of matrix R in QR-factorization ($\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{QR}$) are eucledian distance from column $a_i$ to $\text{span}(a_1, ..., a_{i-1}),~2 \le i \le n$.
I understand that this should be proved using Householder reflections, but I got stuck.
I guess that i-th column of R is a product of A and Householder matrix $H_i$, which reflects i-th column of A about a hyperplane orthogonal to $q_1,...,q_{i-1}$, but I don't understand what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated this is false. Consider for example: $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Clearly $1 \neq \sqrt{2}$.  So let's also assume that $A$ has full rank. Let $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ be the columns of $Q$. Note that $Q^{\mathrm t} A = R$ and so $R_{jk} = \langle q_j, a_k \rangle$. In particular $$a_k = \sum_{j \leq k} \langle q_j, a_k \rangle q_j = \langle q_k, a_k \rangle q_k + \pi_{k-1}(a_k)$$
where $\pi_{k-1}(a_k)$ is the orthogonal projection of $a_k$ onto the span of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_{k-1}\}$.  Rewrite this as $$a_k - \pi_{k-1}(a_k) = \langle q_k, a_k \rangle q_k$$ and take the norm on both sides.  Also note that the result only holds up to a sign in general, but it seems that a usual convention is to take the diagonal entries of $R$ non-negative.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much.